# How can I test the file upload and controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-upload, rspec

My view

```
  <%= form_tag({:action => 'upload_image', :car_id => @car.id}, :multipart => true) do %>
    <label for="upload_file"><%= t('field.select_image') %></label>
    <%= file_field 'upload', 'datafile' %>&nbsp;<%= submit_tag t('field.upload_file') %>
  <% end %>
```

My controller

```
  def upload_image   
    if params[:upload].present? && params[:car_id].present?
      DataFile.save_image_file(params[:upload][:datafile], params[:car_id]) # My methods to save image and other operations with file

    end
    redirect_to images_path(:car_id => params[:car_id])
  end
```

My Rspec Test (doesn't work)

```
before :each do
  @car = FactoryGirl.create(:car)
  @file = fixture_file_upload('/files/test-bus-1.jpg', 'image/jpg')

end

it "can upload a car" do
  post :upload_image, :upload => @file, :car_id => @car.id
  response.should redirect_to images_path(:car_id => @car.id)
end
```

Error: Failure/Error: post :upload_image, :upload => @file, :car_id => @car.id
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `[]' for # File:/tmp/test-bus-1.jpg20120826-29027-plg28d

What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me, based on how you've set up your form (since you are calling `params[:upload][:datafile]`), that you need to change your rspec test to:

```
post :upload_image, :upload => { :datafile => @file }, :car_id => @car.id
```